rpicam Preview Window Scaling
Using a Pi5 with latest OS full install.
Is there any way to make the Preview Window fullscreen, but maintain the pixel size and shape of the CCD?
Essentially, I want to have black space around the Preview Window with the actual image letterboxed and pillarboxed in the center of the Preview Window, which is 1456x1088 in my case using a Global Shutter camera.
Some other way to do this would also work, such as just blanking out the screen in the background while the Preview Window is active. Either in Wayland or from the Command Prompt both work for me.
I'm currently setting it to:
--preview 0,0,1456,1088 --viewfinder-width 1456 --viewfinder-height 1088

I've tried messing around with those values, but it doesn't seem to make any difference as rpicam will just scale the captured image to the edges of the Preview Window no matter what I do. There doesn't appear to be any way to control the scaling behavior of the preview window.
